# Recursive binary search in sorted array c++

Tags: c++, arrays, algorithm, recursion, binary-search

I have to write a recursive function which searches through a sorted array.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int find(int value, int* folge, int max) {

}


int main() {
    int const n = 7;
    int wert1 = 4, wert2 = 13, wert3 = 2, wert4 = 25;
    int folge[n] = {3,4,9,13,13,17,22};
    wert1 = find(wert1, folge, n);
}
```

This is the part of code that was given to us and we have to finish it.
I know how to do this if you have 4 variables available. (min and max)
But I only have three, is there a way to edit the start point of the array which is given to the next function?

Comment: An array name decays to a pointer in ordinary use.  So where it looks like you are passing an array by name, you are really just passing an `int*`.  You can recursively pass a modified `int*` by simply adding an offset to it.  `find(value, folge+m, max-m)`

Comment: @SergeyA Wert is the number we are looking to find in the array

Comment: What is `find` supposed to return when it finds the item you want?  What is it supposed to return when it doesn't find that?

Comment: Very nice question, but I recommend that you translate your variable names into English before posting a question, that makes our job a lot easier.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The function can be written the following way

```
#include <iostream>

int find( int value, int* folge, int max ) 
{
    if ( max == 0 ) return -1;

    int middle = max / 2;

    if ( folge[middle] == value ) return middle;

    bool lower = value < folge[middle];
    int n = lower ? find( value, folge, middle ) 
                  : find( value, folge + middle + 1, max - middle - 1 );

    return n != -1 && !lower ? n + middle + 1: n; 
}

int main()
{
    int const n = 7;
    int wert1 = 4, wert2 = 13, wert3 = 2, wert4 = 25;
    int folge[n] = {3,4,9,13,13,17,22};

    std::cout << wert1 << " = " << find(wert1, folge, n) << std::endl;
    std::cout << wert2 << " = " << find(wert2, folge, n) << std::endl;
    std::cout << wert3 << " = " << find(wert3, folge, n) << std::endl;
    std::cout << wert4 << " = " << find(wert4, folge, n) << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

The program output is

```
4 = 1
13 = 3
2 = -1
25 = -1
```

Or one more test program

```
#include <iostream>

int find( int value, int* folge, int max ) 
{
    if ( max == 0 ) return -1;

    int middle = max / 2;

    if ( folge[middle] == value ) return middle;

    bool lower = value < folge[middle];
    int n = lower ? find( value, folge, middle ) 
                                  : find( value, folge + middle + 1, max - middle - 1 );

    return n != -1 && !lower ? n + middle + 1: n; 
}

int main()
{
    int const n = 7;
    int folge[n] = {3,4,9,13,13,17,22};

    for ( int x : { 2, 3, 4, 9, 13, 17, 22, 25 } )
    {
        std::cout << x << " -> " << find( x , folge, n ) << std::endl;  
    }        

    return 0;
}
```

Its output is

```
2 -> -1
3 -> 0
4 -> 1
9 -> 2
13 -> 3
17 -> 5
22 -> 6
25 -> -1
```

Answer (score 3):

Suppose you have your four-param version:

```
find(value, array, min, max);
```

with the three-parameter version you can call:

```
find(value, array + min, max);
```

Note that the `max`'th element of array is actually `max-min`th element of `array + min`, so depending on your implementation you may want to call

```
find(value, array + min, max - min);
```

Comment: If the last argument is a count, yes.  If it's an index, it needs to be adjusted when the base pointer is changed.

Comment: @BenVoigt in this context, a count and an index are the same thing and either way it needs to be adjusted.  It also needs to be adjusted when the base isn't changed.  Either way, the count is always reduced and in this three parameter form of search the count is always an index.

Answer (score 1):

```
find( &folge[1],...) // ignore first element
```

The address of nth element is an array of size Size-n

Answer (score 0):

You can change the value of the int pointer `folge`

```
int find(int value, int* folge, int max) {
   if (max == 0) {
        return -1;
   }

   int mid=max/2;

   if (value == folge[mid])
   {
        return mid;
   }

   int base=0;

   if (value < folge[mid])
   {
       max=mid-1;
   }
   else
   {
       max-=(mid+1);
       base=mid+1;
   }

   int ret=find(value,folge+base,max);

   if (ret == -1)
   {
       return -1;
   }

   return ret+base;
}
```

Comment: That last line will compile as a comma operator, probably not what you intended.  Also, it is traditional for a binary search function to return the index where the item was found, not its value (which you already know).  And of course, you have a problem of non-termination when `max == 1`, since `max - max/2` doesn't decrease.

Comment: @BenVoigt switched to index based return and cleaned up

Answer (score 0):

If `folge` points to the first element, then `folge+1` will point to the second.

```
int find(int value, int* folge, int max)
{
    int m = max/2;
    if (0 == max)
    {
        return -1;
    }

    if (value == folge[m])
    {
        return value;
    }
    else if (value < folge[m])
    {
        return find(value, folge, m);
    } else
    {
        return find(value, folge + m + 1, max - m - 1);
    }
}
```

Comment: Your discussion/examples of adjusting `folge` are correct, but your binary search logic has a few bugs.